# What does numpy.percentile mean and how to use this for splitting array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand percentiles in numpy.

```
import numpy as np
nd_array = np.array([3.6216, 4.5459, -3.5637, -2.5419])
step_intervals = range(100, 0, -5)

for percentile_interval in step_intervals:
    threshold_attr_value = np.percentile(np.array(nd_array), percentile_interval)
    print "percentile interval ={interval}, threshold_attr_value = {threshold_attr_value}, {arr}".format(interval=percentile_interval, threshold_attr_value=threshold_attr_value, arr=sorted(nd_array))
```

I get a value of these as

```
percentile interval =100, threshold_attr_value = 4.5459, [-3.5636999999999999, -2.5419, 3.6215999999999999, 4.5458999999999996]
```

...

```
percentile interval =5, threshold_attr_value = -3.41043, [-3.5636999999999999, -2.5419, 3.6215999999999999, 4.5458999999999996]
```

What does the percentiles value mean?

- 100% of the values in the array are < 4.5459?
- 5% of values in the array are < -3.41043?

Is that the correct way to read these?

I want to split the numpy array into small sub-arrays. I want to do it based on the percentile occurances of the elements. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by the smallest sub-arrays? How you want to split elements based on percentiles?

Comment: Your assumptions are essentially correct (though I'd replace "lower than" with "lower than or equal to"). The reason for the 5% value not being in the actual array, is that some interpolation is used. The interpolation type can be set by using a parameter, see the documentation for that.

Answer (score 2):

No, as you can see by inspection, only 75% of the values in your array are strictly less than 4.5459, and 25% of the values are strictly less than -3.41043. If you had written less than or equal to, then you would have been giving one common definition of "Percentile" which however happens to also not be what is applied in your case; instead, what's happening is that `numpy` is applying a certain interpolation scheme to ensure that the mapping taking a given number in [0, 100] to the corresponding percentile is continuous and piecewise linear, while still giving the "right" value at ranks corresponding to values in the given array. As it turns out, even this you can do in many different ways, all of which are reasonable, as described in the [Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#The_Nearest_Rank_method). As you can see in [the documentation of `numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html), you have some control of the interpolation behaviour and by default it uses what the Wikipedia article calls the "second variant, $C = 1$".

Perhaps the easiest way to understand the implications of this is to simply plot the result of calculating the different values of `np.percentile` for your fixed length 4 array:

[image]

Note how the kinks are spread evenly across [0, 100] and that the percentiles corresponding to the actual values in your array are given by evaluating `lambda p: np.percentile(nd_array, p)` at 0*100/(4-1), 1*100/(4-1), 2*100/(4-1), and 3*100/(4-1) respectively.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, you should say that  `a = np.percentile(arr, q)` indicates that **nearly** `q%` of elements of `arr` are lower than `a`. Why do I emphasize on **nearly**?

- If `q=100`, it always returns the maximum of `arr`. So, you cannot say that `q%` of elements are "lower than" `a`.
- If `q=0`, it always returns the minimum of `arr`. So, you cannot say that `q%` of elements are "lower than or equal to" `a`.
- In addition, the returned value depends on the type of interpolation.

The following code shows the role of interpolation parameter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> np.percentile(arr, 90) # default interpolation='linear'
4.5999999999999996
>>> np.percentile(arr, 90, interpolation='lower')
4
>>> np.percentile(arr, 90, interpolation='higher')
5
```